# How to connect to Aurora DB from local Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, amazon-rds

I am trying to connect to Aurora DB from my local Jupyter notebook but it is throwing an

```html
import sys
import psycopg2
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from __future__ import division

#Enter the values for you database connection
dbname = ""            # e.g. "compose"
host = "" # e.g.: "aws-us-east-1-portal.4.dblayer.com"
port = ""                 # e.g. 11101 
user= ""        # e.g. "admin"
pwd = ""      # e.g. "xxx"

connstr = "postgresql://" + user + ":" + pwd + "@" + host + ":" + port + "/" + dbname
engine = create_engine(connstr)
```

```html
OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) received invalid response to SSL negotiation: J
```

Is this the Correct way to connect to Aurora DB?

Comment: This indicates it might be the port: https://github.com/boxen/puppet-postgresql/issues/25

Comment: Yes its a port issues, I faced the same and was able to connect after changing the port